# How can I render my form?

Tags: 8

I create a module and I create a template for that .

I use this code in mymodule.module :

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'moduletheme' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'variables' => array('test_var' => NULL),
    ],
  ];
}
```

And I use this code in mymodule/src/Form/MymoduleForm.php :

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $forms['#theme'] = [
        '#theme' => 'moduletheme',
        '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
    ];
    return $forms;
}
```

And I use this code in mymodule/templates/moduletheme.html.twig :

```
<p>Test twig template!</p>
<p>test_var: {{ test_var }}</p>
```

But when I clear cache and refresh my module page , I just see :

```
Test twig template!
test_var:
```

How can I fix this problem in drupal 8 ?

Comment: Try removing `'render element' => 'form'` from your hook_theme, I don't think you want that if you're trying to specify the variables as well.

Comment: I removed that but still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the '#' from the form field key and clear cache. *$forms['theme']* instead of *$forms['#theme']*.

```
$forms['theme'] = [
    '#theme' => 'moduletheme',
    '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
];
```